# Fatal error: Declaration of Temando - Magento 2.3

Tags: php, magento

It is the first time that I ask a question on this community that is literally saving my life everytime.

Now I get to the point, being that I have searched for this all over the internet with no result - so I hope this post will get useful for someone else in future.

I am using Magento 2.3 with the theme Porto in local 127.0.0.1, but when in Default and also Dev mode I run the prompt command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` I instantly get this output:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2>php bin/magento setup:di:compile Compilation
>   was started. Repositories code generation... 1/7
>   [====>-----------------------]  14% 2 secs 54.0 MiBPHP Fatal error: 
>   Declaration of
>   Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionPoint\OrderCollectionPointRepository::save(Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\CollectionPoint\OrderCollectionPointInterface
>   $collectionPoint) must be compatible with
>   Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Repository\OrderCollectionPointRepositoryInterface::save(Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\Delivery\OrderCollectionPointInterface
>   $collectionPoint) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\temando\module-shipping-m2\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionPoint\OrderCollectionPointRepository.php
>   on line 24
>
> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionPoint\OrderCollectionPointRepository::save(Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\CollectionPoint\OrderCollectionPointInterface
>   $collectionPoint) must be compatible with
>   Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Repository\OrderCollectionPointRepositoryInterface::save(Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\Delivery\OrderCollectionPointInterface
>   $collectionPoint) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\temando\module-shipping-m2\Model\ResourceModel\CollectionPoint\OrderCollectionPointRepository.php
>   on line 24

I have tried to disable the module, but nothing happens;
I have tried to run via composer the MageFix downloaded from Github but it's not good for Magento 2.3 (I think).

**Fix**

According to the suggestion of TGR_dev, this is how works the complete fix to this error.

In Vendor folder, I have deleted the folder Temando, then I saw that Magento stopped working - it's normal;

I followed the "command line update" at this guide and reinstalled Magento: https://blog.magestore.com/upgrade-magento-2-3/#a3

**Edit**

Be sure to remove MageFix from the app/code folder if you uploaded it or it will give you error

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same pblm when I upgraded to Magento 2.3.0 from 2.2.6.  Solution: completely delete the vendor/temando folder and all files then reinstall the Magento 2.3.0 upgrade.  This will install the new temando folder and files without the legacy incompatibility error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Magento Root **Directory > Vendor** and **Delete** the **Temando** Folder.

Now Download the **Magento 2.3.0** or your Current Magento Version Archive Folder from Magento Website and Copy the **Vendor > Temando** Folder from the Latest downloaded Magento and Paste it in your Vendor Directory..

Use the compile command again using cmd:

```
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

And it will work..